# How to Combine CASE queries to another JOIN query

Tags: mysql

I have following query:

```
SELECT x.id , x.amount , x.amount as paid_amount , SUM(y.bal) as total, x.reciept_no
  FROM (SELECT *, paid bal 
          FROM challan_1 ) x 
  JOIN (SELECT *, amount bal 
          FROM challan_1 ) y
    ON y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP BY x.id 
HAVING total <= '500'
```

it's working quite fine. And output like

[image]

And then I made a new query that is as below

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN 500-sum(amount) >= 0
                THEN '0'
                ELSE 500-SUM(paid) END) as pending_amt 
  FROM challan_1
```

Output is
[image]

This query returns me a Pending Amount so I need to combine both queries so how can I combine both queries.
I need this pending amount in first query.
This is My [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e67b722/1)

And I need Like This. Where User Have 500 Currency And Have 3 Payment So for that situation Output Should be like this.
[image]
Where 100 Is in pending amount and 200 from user value is debited.

Comment: The second query doesn't make much sense. It's just returning one summary of the entire table, since it has no `GROUP BY`, so why is it also selecting `*`? Those can come from any row in the table.

Comment: Please show sample input and output data which would make it easier to understand your requirements.

Comment: i need only pending amount which returns in second query.

Comment: In the last row: Is the pending amout 100 = 300 (amount) - 100 (paid)? Or is it 100 = 600 (total amount) - 500 (total paid)? Or is there really a fix 500 involved, independent from the record data as your second query suggests?

Comment: amout 100 = 300 (amount) - 100 (paid) So 100 Will Be in Pending Due to User Value will be zero

Comment: Oh, I see I had a typo (the record contains 200 paid of course). So it's 100 = 300 (amount) - 200 (paid)? Why don't you simply add `x.amount - x.paid` to your select list then?

Comment: The Image i inserted is Expected Result That i need. you can see my SQLFiddle. It doesent Fetched the third row. or if you have any suggestion about this you can edit my SQL Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e67b722/1 Here. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. What is `amount` supposed to be? What is `paid` supposed to be? What is the `500` supposed to be? I can imagine a monthly amount to add to a bill and monthly payments to subtract from this, but this doesn't seem to be your case. I can also imagine a total of 500 and monthly payments reducing this, but this doesn't seem to be your case either. I my examples there are two figures (amount / paid) or (500 / paid), but in your case there are three (amount / paid / 500). Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The `sum(amount)` in your results is 600. But your `HAVING` clause stops at `HAVING sum(amount) <= 500`. So do you want result rows with a total up to 500 (two rows) or more? If more, where to stop instead?

Comment: Ok Let Me Explain.
The Amount defines the one type of expense. user have to paid that expense.In this example user have 500 And Expense total is 300+200+100=600 So if user paid 500 So 500 Will be paid to expense.but in last expense you can see that there is 300 Amount And User have only  200 left. So SQL Query cut 200 from user and add 100 in pending amount.if there is no pending amount Status Will be 1 else Status will  be 0.

Comment: Ya But You can remove HAVING And suggest if have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand, but here is my take on this. 500 available. There are records where payments are made. Strange enough even beyond 500, so I assume these are would-be expenses/payments if there were more money available. I stop where payments exceed the 500.

```
SELECT 
  challan.*, 
  SUM(addup.amount) as total_amount, 
  sum(addup.paid) as total_paid,
  sum(addup.amount) - sum(addup.paid) as total_pending,
  sum(addup.amount) <= sum(addup.paid) as status
FROM challan_1 challan
JOIN challan_1 addup ON addup.id <= challan.id 
GROUP BY challan.id
HAVING sum(addup.paid) <= 500
ORDER BY challan.id;
```

If you want to show further records, i.e. get rid of the `HAVING` clause, you'll need another formula for the pending amount, for the highest paid amount possible is 500:

```
SELECT 
  challan.*, 
  SUM(addup.amount) as total_amount, 
  sum(addup.paid) as total_paid,
  sum(addup.amount) - least(500, sum(addup.paid)) as total_pending,
  sum(addup.amount) <= least(500, sum(addup.paid)) as status
FROM challan_1 challan
JOIN challan_1 addup ON addup.id <= challan.id 
GROUP BY challan.id
ORDER BY challan.id;
```

Comment: With more records, it'll take much longer of course :-) Running total queries are usually solved with window functions or cross apply joins. MySQL lacks them both, so you must join each record with all previous ones, as we are doing. This is slow. If you need this faster, I see two options: 1) use another DBMS (e.g. MariaDB as of 10.2), or 2) use a programming language and solve this in a loop. There may be a third option by using variables in MySQL. Look up "running total MySQL" or "emulating sum over with MySQL".

Comment: there are many changes in query but still thank you soo much. it helps me a lot.

Comment: One more Help Please. Check Out This Sql Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e67b722/7. In this fiddle you see that total_pending = 300. how can i do total_pending amout to 100 And count 200 As a total_paid.
as example 300 = paid 200+ 100 pending

Answer (score 0):

Add the subquery as another join.

```
SELECT x.id , x.amount , x.amount as paid_amount , SUM(y.bal) as total, x.reciept_no, p.pending_amt
  FROM (SELECT *, paid bal 
          FROM challan_1 ) x 
  JOIN (SELECT *, amount bal 
          FROM challan_1 ) y
    ON y.id <= x.id 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(amount) <= 500
                          THEN '0'
                          ELSE 500 - SUM(paid)
                     END AS pending_amt
              FROM challan_1) AS p
 GROUP BY x.id 
HAVING total <= '500'
```

Comment: this query working fine. 
But according to my first query it will returns result which is less than 500.
and i apply your query and the value of pending_amt will be remains same.
so what i have to do to change that value as the row will be print as shown in First query Example.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You just said to combine these two queries. The second query isn't grouped by `id`, so it will be the same `pending_amt` for all rows. If that's not what you want, show sample input data and the expected result. A sqlfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Sure. I Post my SQL Schema and also My Expected Result.